# Mostrar imagen en ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, aspx

Estoy haciendo una web en asp.net la cual genera una imagen de lado del servidor y debo mostrársela al usuario en el navegador.

en el **aspx** solo tengo la siguiente linea en el `body`

```
<asp:Image ID="imgd" ImageAlign="Middle" runat="server" />
```

y del lado del servidor en el metodo `Page_Load` tengo la inserción del **path** de la imagen como parámetro a esa etiqueta Imagen.

```
imgd.ImageUrl = Path;
```

**Path**: \[ServerIp]\docs\user\31277_111_A_0045470.png

El **Path** que le proporciono a `imgd` es valido, ya que entro en el servidor y en la ruta especificada tengo generado el archivo. Sin embargo cuando carga la web me muestra el logo de imagen no encontrada.

Comment: Hola, indica en la pregunta el **Path** de la imagen, ya que así es muy difícil ayudarte.

Comment: El servidor [ServerIp] es el mismo donde se encuentra la aplicación asp.net, o es otro diferente?. Me explico, cual es la dirección de tu aplicación?. \docs\user\ es un directorio de tu aplicación?

Comment: La aplicación se encuentra en el mismo servidor si, pero en otra dirección

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que en la propiedad **ImageUrl** debes indicar la **URL** **realtiva** o **absoluta** de la imagen a mostrar.

Para URLs **relativas** (o sea en tu proyecto) el path debería ser así:

```
~/docs/user/31277_111_A_0045470.png
```

Para URL **absolutas** (que es tu caso) el path sería:

```
http://ServerIp/docs/user/31277_111_A_0045470.png
```

Tu problema está en que tu **Path** es una **dirección física** del Servidor. Debes obtener la dirección en **formato URL** a la hora de crear tus imágenes.

Answer (score -1):

El path

```
Path = "\[ServerIp]\docs\user\31277_111_A_0045470.png";
```

no parece correcto, prueba con

```
Path = "~/docs/user/31277_111_A_0045470.png"
```

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y el error persiste

Comment: Pásanos la url correcta y completa en la que puedes acceder con el navegador: ¿es así? http://servidor/docs/user/31277_111_A_0045470.png